# Do you need Xcode to run the rstan or brms packages on RStudio MacOS?

Tags: r, xcode, package, rstan, brms

Do you need Xcode to run the rstan and/or brms packages on RStudio MacOS?

I had to install Xcode to get the rstan and or brms packages on RStudio MacOS. Do I need to keep Xcode on my harddrive to keep the packages work. I don't want to keep it if it can be avoided, since it takes up about 12 GB of space.

FYI, I use a 2013 Macbook Pro with a 2.4 GHz dual-core intel chip, 8 GB or ram, macOS big sur 11.2.2, RStudio Version 1.4.1106, and the R Base Package 4.04.

Answer (score 1):

Anirban Mukherjee writes on the [Stan mailing list](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/update-macos-to-catalina-or-mojave-for-least-problems-with-stan-based-software/19433/15):

> AFAIK it should be sufficient to install command line tools from Xcode (strict subset of what you get with Xcode). If you have Xcode, you don’t need command line tools. To get command line tools, type `xcode-select --install` in a terminal window. The upside is a much smaller download and footprint in terms of disk space.

I don't know if there's an easy way to **delete** all but the command line tools, but you could obviously delete all of Xcode and then re-install only the command-line tools.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and see if I have any success.